# Flink SQL query orc table is null

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

Dears All,

I query the hive table on the **Flink client**, and the returned results are **all NULL**. This hive table is an **ORC table**.I don't know why

Flink SQL> select * from table1 where dt='1609739880002'；

[image]

Flink SQL> select count(*) from `table1` where  dt='1609739880002';

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been resolved. because the fields in the ORC file are inconsistent with the fields in the hive table created.